# Can you put special characters in a table?

Tags: c, special-characters

Language utilized : C Language

IDE : Visual Studio Code

OS : Linux Ubuntu 20.04

Code level : I'm studying computer science in university since september.

Hello, I'm currently working on a game with a dice system, the overlay is the console. I'm drawing the dice with special characters from here : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikip%C3%A9dia:Caract%C3%A8res_sp%C3%A9ciaux/Bordures (sorry it's the french version).

But sometimes, I need to change the look of them. So I created a table (actually multiple, but it's the same problem everywhere), and this table is made of characters. To define what is inside, I put an if/else module, and I just affect characters such as ┃ or ┳ in the cases of the table.

Problem : when I compile the code, I have a warning (-Wall) saying :

```
warning: overflow in conversion from ‘int’ to ‘char’ changes value from ‘14849195’ to ‘-85’ [-Woverflow]
```

Long story short, I just want to be able to affect these characters in my table (I tried with normal characters and it worked perfectly fine).

```
typedef int t_dice[5][2];
typedef char t_diceExtremite[5];
typedef char t_diceMiddle [5][2];

t_dice dice;
t_diceExtremite styleDiceTop,styleDiceBottom;
t_diceMiddle styleDiceMiddle;

for(i=0 ; i<5 ; i++){
    if(dice[i][1]==1){
        styleDiceTop[i] = '┳';
        styleDiceMiddle[i][0] = '┣';
        styleDiceMiddle[i][1] = '┫';
        styleDiceBottom[i] = '┻';
    }else{
        styleDiceTop[i] = '━';
        styleDiceMiddle[i][0] = '┃';
        styleDiceMiddle[i][1] = '┃';
        styleDiceBottom[i] = '━';
    }
}
```

Note : I already wrote 'int i;', and I filled dice[][] with values earlier.

Example of a warning message (this is the same for every line) :

```
/home/myname/code/SAE_1.01/yams.c:82:37: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
82 |             styleDiceMiddle[i][0] = '┣';
   |
/home/myname/code/SAE_1.01/yams.c:81:31: warning: overflow in conversion from ‘int’ to ‘char’ changes value from ‘842347315’ to ‘51’ [-Woverflow]
```

Comment: Some 8-bit character sets include those "table" characters in the range 128-255 but in your text editor they are probably unicode, with a value outside the `char` range, as warned by the compiler.

Comment: If you re-wrote this to take in a string literal instead of a char, then, (depending on the encoding of your editor and terminal,) this might work.

Comment: I don't understand what you think a "table" is.

Comment: Anyway, my *strong* recommendation is that if you want to do *anything properly* with text in 2021, and you are not an expert with a clear use case, you should choose *any language other than* C or C++ (or I guess assembly).

Comment: Oh yeah sorry I think this is a french word Karl Knechtel, this is a group of objects such as float or int, and you can access with a number associated. For example example[2]=5

Comment: Karl I am learning this in University, but I will also see other programming languages such as Java for example, and I already know Python.

Comment: Neil I thought about that, but I guess I'll need to do a 2 level table (and 3 for the styleDiceMiddle one), right ? Because string are already tables themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use wide characters.

i.e.

```
 typedef char t_diceExtremite[5]; -> typedef w_chart t_diceExtremite[5];
```

and

```
styleDiceMiddle[i][0] = '┣'; -> styleDiceMiddle[i][0] = L'┣';
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked ! Well, actually it was wchar_t and I had to include wchar.h, but it solved the problem. I still have problems but it's not related :p. Thanks again ! Have a nice evening

Comment: Actually, I have problems *related* (sorry). Problems : ┃ are replaced by nothing (not even space), ┳ by 3, ┣ by #, ┫ by + and ┻ by ; . I guess this is related to some form of code representing them, but I don't know how to fix that. Should I create a new Question ?

Comment: Use `\x0000` an d look up the code#

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure to understand. Where do I need to use \x0000 ?

Comment: @Cheewy note that on my MSVC the `sizeof(wchar_t)` is `2`, so it cannot hold the value `14849195` mentioned by the compiler.

Comment: Ok, I guess this is why I get nothing or random characters from this method.